# Generating id for tables in liferay?

Tags: liferay-6

For some reasons, I have to build a rating module my own. I use `RatingsEntryLocalServiceUtil` to insert new rating from user.

The method `RatingsEntryLocalServiceUtil.createRatingsEntry(long entryId)` receive a long number as an Id. I want to know are there some built-in ways to get the Id for new ratingsentry or I have to create my own Id?

I use liferay 6.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes
You can use `CounterLocalServiceUtil.increment(RatingsEntry.class)`

CounterLocalServiceUtil.java is utility class for generating ids for models.

Regards

Comment: Thanks a lot. I also just found at http://www.liferaysavvy.com/2013/02/best-way-to-add-data-to-life-ray-tables.html

Answer (score 1):

We can use CounterLocalServiceUtil.increment(RatingsEntry.class) as Pankaj suggested above. But do notice problem encountered while using it as mentioned in thread [CounterLocalServiceUtil.increment(...)](https://web.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/32372043) .

It is suggested above to go with DB sequence generator if possible else add "counter.increment=1" property in portal-ext properties for not skipping whole blocks of keys for primary key usage. This results in small performance hit which needs to be determined satisfactory on case to case basis.